# nao consigo mandar uma mensagem no chat do discord apesar de conseguir mandá-la no console(discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord

estou fazendo um comando de rolagem de dados usando slash commands da v13 do discord.js nunca tinha usado o type:NUMBER antes, então não sei como lidar direito. eu nn sei oq fazer para mandar o resultado para o chat ao inves do console, estive tentando usar `interaction.reply({content:random(1,faces+1)})`, mas não deu certo.
desde de já, agradeço a ajuda.

comando:

```
const { Message, Channel } = require('discord.js')
const Command = require ('../../structures/Command')

module.exports = class extends Command {
    constructor(client){
        super(client,{
            name: 'd',
            description: 'Manda a champola rolar um dado',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'faces',
                    type: 'NUMBER',
                    description: 'escolhe o valor do dado',
                    required: true
                },
            ]
        })
    }

    run = (interaction) => {
        const faces = interaction.options.getNumber('faces')
        const random = (min,max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        console.log(random(1,faces+1))

    }

    
}
```

interaction:

```
const Event = require('../../structures/Event')

module.exports = class extends Event {
    constructor(client){
        super(client,{
            name: 'interactionCreate'
        })
    }

    run = (interaction) => {
       if (interaction.isCommand()){
           const cmd = this.client.commands.find(c => c.name === interaction.commandName)

           if (cmd) cmd.run(interaction)
       }
    }
}
```

index:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Message } = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('./src/structures/Client');

const client = new Client ({
    intents: [
        'GUILDS',
        'GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS',
        'GUILD_MESSAGES',
        'GUILD_INVITES',
        'GUILD_VOICE_STATES',
        'GUILD_MEMBERS',
        'GUILD_PRESENCES'
    ]
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`LIGOU`)
})

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score -1):

consegui, ficou assim se alguem precisar:

```
const { Message, Channel, GuildMember, User } = require('discord.js')
const Command = require ('../../structures/Command')

module.exports = class extends Command {
    constructor(client){
        super(client,{
            name: 'd',
            description: 'Manda a champola rolar um dado',
            options: [
                {
                    name: 'faces',
                    type: 'NUMBER',
                    description: 'escolhe o valor do dado',
                    required: true
                },
            ]
        })
    }

    run = (interaction) => {
        const faces = interaction.options.getNumber('faces')
        const random = (min,max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        if ( interaction.user.id === '390946608575152129')
        interaction.reply({
            content: `resultado:\`${random(1,faces+1)}\`.`,ephemeral:true,
        })
        else
        interaction.reply({
            content: `resultado:\`${random(1,faces+1)}\`.`,ephemeral:false,
        })

    }
}
```